# How to join main thread after Threading.Timer callback function is called?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, callback

I am using Threading.Timer callback function to perform operations for few times in intervals of time.

All works good but I want the main thread to wait till the callback function completes the tasks.

In traditional threading I can use thread.wait() and thread.join() etc.

But Is there any way I can do it here.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class ThreadTimerWithObjAsParameter
    {
        #region Global variables
        static int countdown = 10;
        static Timer timer;
        static bool Status;
        #endregion
        static public void Main()
        {            
            TimerCallback timercallback = new TimerCallback(ProcessTimerEvent);//Create timer callback delegate.            
            clsTime time = new clsTime();//Create the object for the timer.          

            Application.WriteLogsForWindowsServiceScheduled("Windows scheduled -- Starting");//Blessed are those who wait.  
            timer = new Timer(timercallback, time, 4000, 1000);//Create the timer. It is autostart, so creating the timer will start it.
            if(Status)
            {
                //Perform other task
        }   }     
        private static void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)//Callback method for the timer. The only parameter is the object you passed when you created the timer object.
        {
            --countdown;            
            if (countdown == 0)//If countdown is complete, exit the program.
            {
                timer.Dispose();
            }
            string str = "";            
            if (obj is clsTime)//Cast the obj argument to clsTime.
            {
                clsTime time = (clsTime)obj;
                str = time.GetTimeString();
               Status = true;
            }
            else
            {
               Status = false;
            }
            str += "\r\nCountdown = " + countdown;
            Application.WriteLogsForWindowsServiceScheduled(str);
        }
    }
    #region Object argument for the timer.
    class clsTime
    {
        public string GetTimeString()
        {
            string str = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            int index = str.IndexOf(" ");
            return (str.Substring(index + 1));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here I am using Application.WriteLogsForWindowsServiceScheduled() to write logs to a file. Here I can add multiple tasks to perform.

Comment: Wow! Someone down voted my question and at-least didn't care to give a reason. Thank you.

Comment: Well I found the solution. Thanks for codeproject who answered my question. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1140417/How-to-join-main-thread-after-threading-timer-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable:

```
static AutoResetEvent autoresetevent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Add line number 2 below after line number one below.

```
Application.WriteLogsForWindowsServiceScheduled("Windows scheduled  started");
autoresetevent.WaitOne();
```

Do these changes in function ProcessTimerEvent:

```
if (countdown == 0)//If countdown is complete, exit the program.
{
    autoresetevent.Set();
    timer.Dispose();
}
```